# Swing: Create Thread from actionPerformed and periodically update UI from new Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface

I am trying to call a method from an event listener in Swing, that executes a few Server calls and after each updates the UI. Problem is, the UI only updates, when the method returns (after each server call).

Heres the relevant code:

ActionPerformedMethod:

```
private void okayButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {   
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            deletePostsWithID(); // Makes several calls to server and calls updateNumber after each
        }
    });     
}
```

updateNumber Method:

```
public void updateNumber ()
{
    number--;
    progress.setText("Noch " + number + " Beiträge zu löschen");

}
```

I'll be happy to provide whichever further information is needed.

Comment: You're not starting any thread in that code. Really start a thread, or use a SwingWorker, which will do that for you, and provide the methods used to publish results in the EDT.

Comment: All you're doing with `invokeLater(...)` is to guarantee that the `deletePostsWithID()` is called ***on*** the Swing event thread, not off it. Use a SwingWorker.

Comment: Look up [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) as this will answer all.